# telegram bot keyboard markup doesn't work using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot, custom-keyboard

I have this code, but it doesn't work to showing  message and  keyboard while using Function Keyboard that I made.

```
function sendText(id,text) {
    var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
 function Keyboard (id, text, reply_markup ){
    var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text + "&reply_markup=" + reply_markup ;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doPost(e) {
// this is where telegram works
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var text = data.message.text;
    var id = data.message.chat.id;
 if (text == "/start"){
    var message = "Selamat datang. Untuk mencari data pelanggan silahkan memasukkan @ODP_NAME.%0AContoh : @ODP-UBN-FAC/100";
    var opts =  JSON.stringify({ 
            keyboard: [['OK','Cancel']],
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            resize_keyboard: true
            })
        ;
//sendText(id, "hola", opts);
  Keyboard(id,"hi", opts);

}
}
```

**and then i try to use Function sendText() like this to make the url true, but it's only give me the text and not showing the keyboard. **

```
 sendText(id,"hi", {reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ 
            keyboard: [['OK','Cancel']],
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            resize_keyboard: true
   })
});
```

**Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?**

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read, and SHOUTING will not get you help any faster. There are Shift keys on both sides of your keyboard to make them easy to reach and use for a reason. Please do so instead of using your CAPS LOCK.

Comment: i'm sorry if i got wrong, i'm a newbie. but thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

instead of use get try use post
example :

```js
var keyBoard =JSON.stringify({ 
            "keyboard": [["OK","Cancel"]],
            "one_time_keyboard":true,
            "resize_keyboard":true
            });

var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11";

function replyKeyboard(){ 
  var formData = {
    'chat_id': "1234567",
    'text': 'Hello',
    'reply_markup': keyBoard
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?", options);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your reply_markup should look like this:

```
{ 
    keyboard: [[{text: 'OK'}, {text: 'Cancel'}]],
    one_time_keyboard: true,
    resize_keyboard: true
}
```

Comment: i've try that, but it's still giving invalid argument. on the response fetchUrl

Comment: i just got this work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887329/google-app-script-telegram-bot-custom-keyboard  just understand now how to use it. thanks for answering